# VB.Net equivalent to JavaScript charCodeAt

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

My code in javascript is:

```
var start = s1.charCodeAt(0);
var end   = s2.charCodeAt(0);
var arr = new Array(n);
var m = Math.pow(((end - start) + 1),n);
for (var i=0; i<n; i++)
arr[i] = s1;
for (var i=0; i<m-1; i++){
for(var j=n-1; j>=0;--j) {
var t = arr[j].charCodeAt(0);
t++; arr[j] = String.fromCharCode(t);
if (arr[j].charCodeAt(0)<=end) {
break;} else { arr[j] = s1 ;}}
var chlg = arr.join("");
```

I'm converting the above code to VB.NET - does anyone know what an equivalent method to `charCodeAt` would be in VB.NET?

Comment: Why Java tag then? Do you want to convert to Java or Javascript? Both are not similar except first 4 letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringName.chars(i) and Asc().
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the index between the brackets after ElementAt:

```
StringName.ToCharArray().ElementAt()
```